# Why did Christopher Tolkien think the idea of Bilbo's marriage was never going to work?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, christopher-tolkien

On page 36 in *Return of the Shadow* (*The History of Middle-earth* vol. 6), Christopher Tolkien writes:

> We come now therefore to a further stage, where the 'long-expected
> party' is still Bingo's, not Bilbo's, but Bingo is his nephew, not his son,
> and Bilbo's marriage (**as was inevitable, I think**) has been rejected.

(Emphasis mine).

This remark struck me as odd, and I was wondering if anyone might have an idea as to why he wrote that. Perhaps something written elsewhere in HoMe or other sources sheds some light on this?

Answer (score 12):

This strikes me just as CT seeing what the plot requirements are. Bilbo basically needs to be a bachelor in order to be able to leave the Shire without complications. Bilbo needs to be someone in the Shire, but also not quite of it - everyone thinks he's a bit of a weirdo - and a spouse would complicate that. It also allows him to leave Bag-end to Frodo (and do the humorous distribution of his goods to relatives).